# vbCFBitmap Variable Not defined

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using MS-Access 2007 VBA.

I am attempting to convert a pdf to an image. I found this chunk of code online, but they failed to provide all the references. My compile is failing on vbCFBitmap. Does anyone know where this reference comes from?

```
             Dim MyAcro As New AcroApp
        Dim MyPDF  As New AcroPDDoc
        Dim MyPage As AcroPDPage
        Dim MyPt As acrobat.AcroPoint
        Dim MyRect As AcroRect
        Dim MyData As DataObject
        Dim strPathString As String
        Dim MyPath As String
        Dim SaveToPath As String
        Dim mysavepath As String
       MyPath = "\\spfs1\stone\Long Term Share\gentex_ppaps\gentex_ppaps_raw\Supplier Request Number 3034910, Gentex Part Number 345-2120-000 Revision (003).pdf"
       mysavepath = "C:\out"
        ' open the PDF
        MyPDF.Open (MyPath)
        Set MyPage = MyPDF.AcquirePage(0)
        ' Convert Point to Twips for document
        Set MyPt = New AcroPoint
        'Define the rectangle that contains the PDF form
        Set MyRect = New acrobat.AcroRect
            MyRect.Top = 0
            MyRect.Left = 0
            MyRect.Right = MyPt.x
            MyRect.bottom = MyPt.y
           ' Copy the PDF image to the clip board
        Call MyPage.CopyToClipboard(MyRect, MyRect.Left, MyRect.Top, 100)
        ' Capture image from clip board to data object
        Set MyData = Clipboard.GetData(vbCFBitmap)
        'Save the data object
        SavePicture MyData, mysavepath
        ' Clean up
        Set MyAcro = Nothing
        Set MyPDF = Nothing
        Set MyPage = Nothing
        Set MyPt = Nothing
        Set MyRect = Nothing
        Set MyData = Nothing
```

Comment: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?608372-RESOLVED-Save-picture-to-file-using-Clipboard-GetData-or-controlRange

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's likely VB6 code, not VBA.

`vbCFBitmap` is a system global, and thus not imported using any references.

However, that's just a copy of the [Windows Standard Clipboard Formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/standard-clipboard-formats), thus `vbCFBitmap` is equal to 2. You can use 2 instead.